# Obj-C: application:openFiles: (multiple files dropped) not receiving all files. Bug?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, drag-and-drop, info.plist

Closest one I found is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778932/cocoa-app-not-receiving-all-dropped-files-in-applicationopenfiles
But it hasn't been answered.

My Problem is this,
So let's say I am dropping 4 files on my dock application:

- test.xls
- test.rtf
- test.jpg
- test.pdf

If I go debug my program it shows this:

[Debug log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAYe5.png)

As you can see the .jpg file is not in there.
This also happens for: .py, other image types, .txt files
I have found out that if I drop files only from that group (.py .jpg .txt) then it recognizes all of them.

My Info.plist looks like this:

```
<?xmlversion="1.0"encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPEplistPUBLIC"-//Apple//DTDPLIST1.0//EN""http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plistversion="1.0">
<dict>
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<string>en</string>
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
<dict>
<key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
<string>AllFiles</string>
<key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
<string>application.icns</string>
<key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
<string>Viewer</string>
<key>LSHandlerRank</key>
<string>Alternate</string>
<key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
<array>
<string>public.item</string>
</array>
</dict>
</array>
```

I don't know where the error is in here, maybe it's a bug? Or did I configure my info.plist wrong?

I hope someone can help me and thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set in info.plist like this

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
            <array>
                <string>*</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>Files</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>public.data</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

and use this method in AppDelegate.m

```
-(void)application:(NSApplication *)sender openFiles:(NSArray *)fileList{
 // use fileList array 
}

-(BOOL)application:(NSApplication *)sender openFile:(NSString *)filename{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I changed my info.plist like yours but it still has the same problem. I am using this method: - (void)application:(NSApplication *)theApplication openFiles:(NSArray<NSString *> *)filenames{

Comment: if you set like this then it should working 
          <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>public.data</string>
            </array>

Comment: You can add here file type also. like only image, pdf or only folders or anything else.

Comment: I copied exactly your info.plist snippet but it still doesn't work. It accepts every filetype but e.g. not .jpg and .rtf together. It will then only recognize the .rtf file, .jpg will be ignored and I don't know why.

Comment: Here some time files get one by one in some file groups.

like if you drag multiple file then may this method will called multiple times.
but it will gave all file list.

Comment: I'm not sure If I understood you correctly. If I drag e.g. 10 files (only .jpg), then the array has 10 objects in it. But then if I drag e.g. 12 files (10 .jpg, 1 .rtf, 1.xml) it will only show 2 objects: the .xml file and the .rtf file. All 10 .jpg files will be ignored (Why?). It works but somehow .py .txt and image files are causing problems.

Comment: what i trying to say. you will get all file list. just wait 
-(void)application:(NSApplication *)sender openFiles:(NSArray *)fileList  
this method will call multiple times. and you get the whole list may in multiple groups.

Comment: Oh okay, thank you I will try that. And for multiple groups, can I put those groups into one single group together?

Comment: Yes make one global Mutable array and add those list in that array on by one

Comment: -(void)application:(NSApplication *)sender openFiles:(NSArray *)fileList
Will called multiple time while drag 12 files (you are saying) 
and you will get all files

Comment: I had a [NSApp terminate] in this method which caused the problem. Your solution was correct, thank you.

Comment: Hey, could you also tell me how to terminate my application if the "openFiles:(NSArray *)fileList method is completed with ALL filetypes? There seems to be no event handlers for this..

Comment: You may need to make one global array and add fileList  on that array. At the end of this method you have to check array contain all file typelist then terminate app otherwise continue.

Comment: Yes but the problem is, how can I check if all filetype lists have been processed? Is there a way to find out how many groups there are?

Comment: This is pretty stupid behaviour with Apple Events if you ask me. Having the same problem. If 40 files are opened at once, why can't the app just receive those 40 files as an event in one go? It IS a single event.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem and here is how I solved it:

```
@property (strong) NSMutableArray *openFilesList;
@property (strong) NSTimer *openFilesTimer;

...

@synthesize openFilesList;
@synthesize openFilesTimer;

...

-(void)init {
    openFilesList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    openFilesTimer = nil;
}

-(void)application:(NSApplication *)sender openFiles:(NSArray *)filenames {
    if (openFilesTimer) {
        [openFilesTimer invalidate];
    }
    [openFilesList addObjectsFromArray:filenames];
    openFilesTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.2f
                                                      target:self
                                                    selector:@selector(processOpenFiles)
                                                    userInfo:nil
                                                     repeats:NO];
}

-(void)processOpenFiles {
    NSArray *filenames = [openFilesList copy];
    openFilesTimer = nil;
    [openFilesList removeAllObjects];

    // Do your processing with filenames
}
```

Comment: First of all, thank you this is exactly what I was going to do next. I've encountered another strange behavior with tar.gz files, it gets thrown in a single group and if I drag 3 files from 3 diffrent groups (.jpg / .rtf / .tar.gz) it only processes 2 of those groups. Any idea?

Comment: Are all three file extensions defined in your info.plist?